# Git checking out problem [fatal: early EOFs]

Tags: git, ubuntu-9.10, binaryfiles

I'm running a Ubuntu (9.10) server with Git (latest from Ubuntu package manager) installed. Access to the Git is via SSH. On windows machines, I'm using Cygwin to push/pull code.

I can push my project code onto the server but when I do a clone or pull, it returns a [fatal: early EOFs] error at about 75-80%.

Upon further investigation, it seems like textual data has no issue when pulled/cloned but when the jar files and images are pulled from Git, the error will occur.

Any suggestion/advice that can help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

What is the Git version are you using ([Ubuntu 9.10 packages mentions 1.6.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/devel/git-core))

A recent thread reported a similar [issue with Git1.7.1](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-12/msg00740.html), although it was [from a Cygwin environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493645/git-fatal-remote-end-hung-up/1954050#1954050).

```
$ git clone git:/repo/git/acl acl.test
  Initialized empty Git repository in /c/tmp/acl.test/.git/
  remote: Counting objects: 9205, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3300/3300), done.
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOFs:  62% (5708/9205)
  fatal: index-pack failed
```

Did you try downgrade your Git (on the server side and/or [the client side](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-12/msg00756.html)) and see if the problem persists?

---

As the OP [Style](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300552/style) reports in the comments, the message can also be trigger by an incorrect protocol:

```
git+ssh://
```

instead of just:

ssh:// + git command

Comment: Sorry to reply so late, the solution seems to be due to how I log into the repository. Previously I was using "git+ssh://". When I changed to log in using "ssh://" followed by git command, the error is gone :)

Comment: @Style: thank you for the feedback. I have update my answer to reflect the root cause you mention.

Comment: most welcome :) I want to mark your answer as useful but not enough reputation points >< But I'm really amazed and loving the community here. Nice to meet you! Stack overflow rocks, Git too ;)

Answer (score 4):

@rickb I found that running

```
git config --add core.compression -1
```

in the client (cygwin) repository fixed it.

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 12.10, git 1.7.10.4

Comment: Worked for me, MacOS X 10.8.4, git version 1.7.12.4

Answer (score 3):

`git config --global --add core.compression -1`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the problem went away after I enabled Compression in the ~/.ssh/config file.  God knows why.

Answer (score 0):

Try [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). I had the same issue with cygwin's git, and when I fetched the same repository using msysgit it worked first time.

See also this thread: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-09/msg00832.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424

also you can try: git config --global core.compression 0 tp disable the compressions.