# how can i push my existing project in visual studio 2015 to TFS

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have an existing Cordova project on visual studio 2015 and i need to push it on Team Foundation Server so how?

I tried doing:

> file --> new  --> Project from existing code, and then choose Cordova

so now i want to push it on Team Foundation Server..

but it didn't work by command line so i installed visual studio 2015 to try push it

Comment: It didn't work by command line: which command line did you type, what was the error message?

Comment: Git push -f origin master ... It say writing objects 100% done and then hang out ,, stuck on this phase

Comment: What version of Git are you using? On which OS (W7,8,10? 32bits? 64bits)? What does `git remote -v` returns? What does `git status` returns?

Comment: Gut verrsion 2.9.0 64 bit windows 8

Comment: Git remote -v : origin https://tfs...... One for fetch and one for push

Comment: Git status : on branch master .. Your branch is up to date with origin master . Nothing to commit working directory clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a git push should work, check if you didn't add and commit a huge file in your project.

Or at least, try

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Both cases were seen in "[Git hangs while writing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887228/6309)".

But if `git status` reports "Your branch is up to date with origin master.", then the previous push must have succeeded. At least try a `git fetch` to check if the remote repo updates anything.

Comment: i did it .. with same result it still hang s

Comment: and also with git config --global ssl.postBuffer 524288000

Comment: @JoeSleiman Just in case, can you unzip and try with Git 2.10.0? https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.10.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.10.0-64-bit.7z.exe

Comment: oops now it's working i don't know why ??? even i did all what you say before ...omg....any way thankss @VonC if i face any other problem i will post it here

Comment: but if someone have solution by visual studio 2015... cz it may done by visual studio when i click publish so i think it pushed to tfs from visual studio not from cmd