# Issue with git push command on gitHub

Tags: git, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc3oW.png)

```
 % git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 4.49 MiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

I am unable to push changes to remote directory and terminal hangs at this line. The command does not throw any error or return anything and the terminal is hung with cursor blinking on the next line.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Please don't use screenshot while you can copy & paste the contents into your question.

Comment: Try using `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`, then try the command again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git hangs while writing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887228/git-hangs-while-writing-objects)