# Git fetch github: Index-pack failed

Tags: windows, git, bash, github, fetch

When running the command ***git fetch github*** , I get the following error:

***fatal: write error: Broken pipe93), 23.23 MiB | 635 KiB/s***
***fatal: index-pack failed.***

I then get a "git.exe has stopped working" error message while Windows attempts to find a solution to the problem.

Running ***GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch github*** doesn't give any additional details.

***Note**: I can perform a **git fetch github [branch name]** directly and that works without error*

When I try "Repository > Compress Database" in Git Gui, I get "Error: Command Failed". I get the same error when I try "Repository > Verify Database".

How do I get around this? It's almost like my local repo is corrupt.

**System Info**

- *Git Bash: 1.7.4-preview20110204
- Windows 7 64-bit*

Comment: What does `git fsck` tell you?

Comment: Are you accessing the GitHub repository with SSH or HTTP(S) protocol? Historically, msysgit has had some trouble with SSH connections...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

- check if the problem persists in a *new* local repo (so, after re-cloning your GitHub repo)
- check if raising the postBuffer size can alleviate the problem

  git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

(as mentioned in "[The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/6849424#6849424)")