# Github Status : Error in Pushing...!! Aborting?

Tags: github, git-push

I'm trying to push a build in Github and I keep on getting "Aborting" status and i have tried multiple times and I experience the same error.Not sure,how to solve this issue ? Any help or advice on this would be really great.

```
Commit successful
Username for 'https://github.com': ########
Password for 'https://######@github.com': 
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
Error in Pushing..!!  Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you having any large file in your repo.
For instance, a config like this one can help:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "32m"
```

It represents the maximum size of memory that is consumed by each thread in [`git-pack-objects`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects) for pack window memory.

You also have ([as I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006808/6309)):

```
git config http.postBuffer 52428800
```

You can also use a tool like [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to get rid of any too large file.