# Get Error while cloning for BitBucket repeatedly

Tags: eclipse, git, clone, bitbucket

For SourceTree or Eclipse, I was unable to clone the repositories. Every time I try to clone that, I get the message:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504
```

Any clue what is causing this? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can find a [similar issue in this thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/21630795/git-clone-failing):

> The HTTP error 504 is related to a Gateway Timeout, what means your request couldn’t be completed.
>
> When attempting to clone your Git repository over HTTP, it probably means that there's a size issue. Git is not designed to perform well over HTTP with repositories larger than about 1 GB.
> Over HTTP, Git has to be served using FastCGI and so the FastCGI process can sometimes time out before the command can return results

You have some workaround (for push in Stash, but applicable to git clone in general) in "[error: RPC failed result=22 - Push to Stash fails](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/error%3A+RPC+failed+result%3D22+-+Push+to+Stash+fails)"

You can diagnose the root cause with more information displayed when you set:

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

`http.postBuffer` might be an issue, as in "[Git fetch github: Index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006808/6309)".