# rsync git big repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a git repository onto my local machine, but it is saying "`malloc failed`" because the repository is too big.

Does anyone know the exact rsync command I could use to copy over the directory? or is there anything else I can do to clone a big repository?

I tried rsyncing but it gives me the following error:

```
Invalid command: 'rsync --server --sender -v . username/dir.git'
  You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
  Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
  GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(463) [receiver=2.6.8]
```

I get the following error when trying to use git clone:

```
remote: Counting objects: 52708, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (52188/52188), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1471836719 bytes)
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Can you try again your clone command after a `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/6849424#6849424?

Comment: @VonC - shouldn't you be asking which protocol is being used in the first place? That setting wouldn't matter if ssh / git is being used?

Comment: Do you really use `rsync` to clone it? :?

Comment: nope git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000 did not work. :( I have edited my question above to clarify the errors I get. thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how big is the repo?

Comment: @lanojlds: true, I assumed http-based clone. And anyway, the malloc is about the triple of the `postBuffer` size I was suggesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a newer version of `git`. Newer version can handle this. 
or, if you are using new version already, set `git config core.bigFileThreshold` to a smaller size.

Comment: I didn't know about that particular setting. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using ulimit to allow more memory to be used by the git process.

- ulimit -m *XXX*
- ulimit -v *YYY*

Answer (score 0):

If you have one really large file, I don't think you have any other option but trying to remove it from your repo, assumming:

- you have access to the remote server
- nobody else has managed to clone it (since it would change the history in the process, which would make any future pull problematic for existing clones).

See the [section "Removing a File from Every Commit" from the Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html#the_nuclear_option_filterbranch).

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f bigFile' -- --all
```

Check also the [section "Checklist for Shrinking a Repository" of `git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository).

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a remote repository. (Naissa's trying to create a local clone.) And what makes you think no-one was able to clone the repository?

Comment: @Christopher: what makes me think that no-one was able to clone that repo was the early hour of the morning when I initially answered this question ;)