# When I'm trying to do git pull origin Beta --it just hangs while unpacking

Tags: git, pull

When I am trying

**git pull origin Beta**

remote: Counting objects: 36, done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.

Unpacking objects:  97% (35/36)

My Git is not moving forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git stuck on Unpacking Objects phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731785/git-stuck-on-unpacking-objects-phase)

Comment: Thanks man @Hoall