# git pull - completely stuck

Tags: git, bitbucket

I tried to take updates using `git pull`. But it is getting stuck with the output below:

```
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Unpacking objects:  18% (2/11)
```

I am using `git version 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)`. Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of remote do you use?

Comment: I mean where is the remote repository placed? Github, bitbucket or custom git server?

Comment: Have you allowed enough time for it to complete - large repos (especially if you haven't fetched from them in a while) - can take a while (even more so on slow/unreliable connections)

Comment: bitbucket repository

Comment: What's the size or your repo? As @jon-clements mentioned it takes some time to compress big files...

Comment: @JonClements Yes I did. But still not completing

Comment: Now, I am getting this error `error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703069/6309?

Comment: check if any recipe from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7731785/2303202 helps.

Comment: does git process consume CPU being stuck? Does it read anything from network or is waiting for data? Make sure you checked the correct process, there is some tree of them.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally this event occurs due to slow or interrupt internet connection or a major change in the repository. So almost always you need enough time to get the job done