# error: gnutls_handshake() failed GIT repository

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-10.04

The following error appears when I try to clone git repository. I have the rsa public keys configured properly as well.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/blah/blah.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/arun/.git/
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was
       received. while accessing https://github.com/blah/blah.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be used to a [GnuTLs or pycurl bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pycurl/+bug/926548)

> The following is the new method for pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl
sudo apt-get source python-pycurl
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo dpkg-source -x pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3.dsc
cd pycurl-7.19.0
# remove the HAVE_CURL_GNUTLS=1 in the following file
sudo vim debian/patches/10_setup.py.dpatch
# remove the HAVE_CURL_GNUTLS=1 in the following file
sudo vim setup.py
# replace all gnutls into openssl in the following file
sudo vim debian/control
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
sudo dpkg -i ../python-pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. During the last step, I get the following error. Do you have any clues?

$ sudo dpkg -i ../python-pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing ../python-pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ../python-pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb

Comment: @user1514027 I suppose it depends on the exact `.deb` file name built by the previous step (the `dpkg-buildpackage`). You need to have a look and search for the actual name generated.

Comment: I followed this solution, deviations included the source source file presenting as pycurl_7.19.0-3.dsc instead of pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3.dsc.  I also found it necessary to NOT edit patch file, doing so caused an MD5 failure on the build.

Comment: In the end, the behavior is unchanged, perhaps I need to find a way to really stop that macro from being defined. Perhaps I can manually make the changes to setup.py and stop the patch from being applied?

Comment: Edited the patched setup.py to remove the macro definition, then deleted the patched file and removed reference in /debian/patches/00list.  Build appeared to work, but no change in behavior still.  Dang.  Would my certificate failing cause a similar problem?

Comment: @2NinerRomeo I didn't find any new information about that thread, so I will be interested with what you will come up.

Comment: Added an answer for what finally worked for me.  I'm not sure how to distinguish whether I am using pycurl or not.

Comment: In my case, I get an error on fetching source for python-pycurl - `E: Unable to find a source package for pycurl` - http://hastebin.com/axezunupoz.mel

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem, and it took me a while to find the solution. I kept thinking that I was missing a package somewhere. I didn't want to recompile Git, since I was already using the latest version, and I was pretty sure that the problem wasn't Git itself.

My problem was my `.gitconfig` file. The problem only occurred on an old Linux server that had been upgraded many times over the years. At some point, for some reason I don't recall, I had explicitly specified `sslVersion = sslv3` in my `.gitconfig` file.

When I saw that, the lightbulb went on, since I know that SSL V3 has been deprecated due to security concerns, and that most people should be using TLS instead. For instance, see RFC 7568, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568

So my fix involved either deleting the offending `sslVersion = sslv3` line from my `~/.gitconfig` file, or changing this:

```
[httpd] 
    sslVersion = sslv3
```

to this:

```
[httpd]
    sslVersion = tlsv1.2
```

Removing the line and letting Git/libcurl negotiate the encryption seemed like the best choice, since TLS v1.3 is in the works, and I don't want to encounter this problem again in the future!

Comment: Good suggestion. There are a number of [git-config options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpsslVersion) that might lead to an issue like this or could be used as a work around.

Answer (score 5):

In My case, It appears I was not using pycurl, so the above solution did not work for me.  What DID work was a rebuild of git-core modified to use openssl instead of gnutls.

Instructions are here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-falied

I had substitute "git-core" for "git" in most places, the .dsc (package information file?) turned up as git-core_1.7.0.4-1ubuntu0.2.dsc, and the .deb package came out as git-core_1.7.0.4-1ubuntu0.2_i386.deb.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when tried `sudo git fetch` from a directory my own user didn't have enough rights to. I moved repository to `/tmp` and continued my work.

Don't forget `/tmp` gets erased after reboot.

Comment: only on some systems

Answer (score -2):

In my case worked, mixing the solutions of @Rick and @m0j0

First execute these commands:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

After add or modify `~/.gitconfig`

```
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

Set this:

```
[httpd] 
    sslVersion = sslv3
```

Answer (score -3):

For me, it ended up being that SSL certificate was self-signed. Give this a try

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Comment: Never do this. It disables authentication on _every TLS connection_ ever made by `git`, removing protection against several kinds of attacks.