# Homebrew install error: Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n

Tags: homebrew

I get this error message when I install homebrew with `curl: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`

> The error message is as following: error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP
>   code = 200MiB | 55 KiB/s      fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly fatal: early EOF fatal: recursion detected in die handler
>   Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have the same problem. anybody knows?

Comment: [Try this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=301663284). It may help you. It seems I solved it by this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it was some problem with git (new computer).

What I did to solve the problem:

Fixed my git setup, then ran

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git
```

Then

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, would you mind clarifying how you "fixed your git set up"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I met similar issue, tried below but not yet solved:
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000

ref similar post: [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

i now still block at here with this error:

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': SSLRead() return error -9806
Error: Failure while executing: git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core --depth=1
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core

Not sure if linked with my poor network connection recently