# What is the meaning of 'RPC failed' in git?

Tags: git

When using git, I have met many kinds of RPC failed.

e.g.:

> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0

and When I google "git rpc failed", I can get many results especially from stackoverflow:

> error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413
>   error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
>   error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411
>   ...

But, what's the meaning of RPC failed, how can we troubleshooting them, and where can we find a list about what's the meaning of those error codes?

Comment: Different error codes signify different errors, but you should probably google for your correct error code. 56 usually means that the http post size is too big. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning

Answer (score 1):

One potential reason is that you have old version of git. Try updating your git to a more recent version. Minimum supported version for github is 1.7.10 for instance.

The specific error for you cold be about http post buffer, which might have to be increased:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

[The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

A workaround might be to get ssh url for the same repo and use that.

Comment: But, what I am asking is how to solve this kind of problem, not just  this problem.