# git clone fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

Im an trying to clone the zephir project to my CentOS box, but I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git clone https://github.com/phalcon/zephir
Cloning into 'zephir'...
usage: git fetch-pack [--all] [--quiet|-q] [--keep|-k] [--thin] [--include-tag] [--upload-pack=<git-upload-pack>] [--depth=<n>] [--no-progress] [-v] [<host>:]<directory> [<refs>...]
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried git config --global --add core.compression -1 but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning

Comment: Can you try again with the command `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/phalcon/zephir` and post whatever errors occur around where it stops?

Comment: tried... no luck same error

Comment: @user3360140 The error depends on the so many factors. What I faced the situation like I tried to clone the repo when internet connection was too slow. Then I got this error.

Comment: Can you use ssh cloning?