# GIT error while push: error: RPC failed; result=7, HTTP code = 401

Tags: git, push

While I trying to push some commits to remote server, I get this response (after waiting about 5 minutes):

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" events_devel:events_devel

Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Writing objects: 100% (47/47), 475.15 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 47 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=7, HTTP code = 401
Everything up-to-date
```

I was try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424, but same result.
Remote server not GitHub... its the corporate server.
Pulling works as it should.

Comment: are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Yes, we are VPN link. But as I said, pulling is OK. I forgot to write that I pushing 0.5 MB file and other small source files.

Comment: is the `origin` remote using the `ssh://` or  the `http://` protocol?

Comment: Thomasleveil: http://

Comment: if you can, try with `ssh://` and if it works, then you know you have to focus your efforts on the http protocol

Comment: no, ssh not support by remote server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with the stable Git for Windows (1.9.5) for updating using http and windows or basic auth.

Try to upgrade to the 2.4.6-release candidate version. You can find it [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

[Source](https://pedroliska.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/git-push-hangs-when-windows-git-client-pushes-to-teamfoundation-git-server/)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely some network issue on the remote side.

Try using different protocol instead, such as ssh.

To debug the issue, you can specify some extra variables for git command, e.g.

> `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_CURL=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git push --progress origin`

For SSH issues, try:

```
echo 'ssh -vvv $*' > ssh && chmod +x ssh
GIT_SSH="$PWD/ssh" git push --progress origin
```

Or use `strace` to debug the process, e.g.

```
strace -f git push
```

See also: [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/55075)