# git push taking ages

Tags: git, push

Im trying to push my git repo and it's taking a very long time.

```
Counting objects: 17496, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6920/6920), done.
Writing objects:  94% (16504/17496), 44.43 MiB | 103.00 KiB/s
```

It's been sitting `16504/17496` for 30 minutes now. If it just needs time I'm happy to leave it but considering it got to `94%` in less than 2 minutes I'm concerned something is broken.

What should I do?

P.S. It's just a very basic magento installation with no media.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may happen

- If there are large unignored files in the repo.
- If the `http.postBuffer` size is very less. You can change the size using `git config --global http.postBuffer <size>`. This is the Maximum size in bytes of the buffer used by smart HTTP transports when POSTing data to the remote system.

This might also help, have a look at it: [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/6849424#6849424)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen no progress being reported by GIT when it encounters a very large file. I've used a performance monitor to check that the communication is still happening. If you see that grinding to a halt, things will take forever to push.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using IntelliJ go to the bottom of the window and select Version Control.View Log section of the version control and then you will find the history of your commits. Now you would want to rebase your branch head to the commit right before the commit where you pushed a really large file by mistake. But you obviously dont wanna lose your changes. To do so, right click on the commit before the wrong commit and select option : RESET CURRENT BRANCH TO HERE click on this option will prompt you to a modal window with a few options.Choose this particular option if u dont wish to lose any changes:

SOFT : Files wont change, differences will be staged for commit

Comment: There is no indication that the thread creator is using any IDE therefore your answer will not help.