# How to check post buffer size before clone git repository?

Tags: git, github

When I try to take a clone of the git repository, I get error message

> The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning

I search a bit over it and found solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning) but I would like know what is the current allocation. So how do I check that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run this command in root folder of git repository ( by doing so you will search in `~/.gitconfig` and `.git/config` files ):

```
git config --get http.postBuffer
```

If it shows nothing, then used default value ( 1 MiB from [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httppostBuffer) ).