# Git cloning process failes with curl 56 error

Tags: git, tfs, clone

When I try to clone the repository from **TFS**, I ended up with the below error :

> ```
> Cloning into 'Repo'...
> error: RPC failed; curl 56 Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> fatal: early EOF
> fatal: index-pack failed
> ```

Tried many solutions by increasing buffer size but none of them worked for me.

Comment: First time I see such error, can you share more info, e.g. version for involved software (TFS, Git, OS), protocol and authentication used, definition of remotes...

Comment: TFS2013 is the remote repository with latest git installed locally. More than 1K commits have been done with no issues but now it throws the above error while cloning. Git clone/pull throws the same error but some times it shows there is a bad offset.

Comment: Does it work when you clone from Visual Studio? (which doesn't rely on the Git client)...

Comment: No it doesn't...same error. Does it occur because of some bad commits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem while commiting/pushing and [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning) helped by raising the buffer with a command like

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar error during Git clone process [Git Clone Fails - error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-779171803.html) Please try the solution in the link.

Execute the following in the command line before executing the Git command:

```
1  set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1

2  set GIT_TRACE=1

3  set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is maybe the type of compression used, try different type of compression :

```
git config --global core.compression 1
```

or

```
git config --global core.compression 9
```

or

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

or

```
git config --global core.compression 6
```

Chances are one of thoses will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is, as this error may occur for memory requirement of git.

I have added these lines to my global git configuration file .gitconfig which is present in $USER_HOME

i.e `C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\.gitconfig`

```
[core] 
packedGitLimit = 512m 
packedGitWindowSize = 512m 
[pack] 
deltaCacheSize = 2047m 
packSizeLimit = 2047m 
windowMemory = 2047m
```