# Getting the Fatal Error while cloning the Project from the TFS through Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, git-clone

Getting the **Fatal Error** while cloning the project from the **TFS** using Visual Studio 2019

[image]

I have tried by updating the Git and VS 2019 with the latest versions. Still getting the same issue. Please help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Satish Kumar S, according to your comment you also get error when using CMD command line.  This issue may not related  your Visual Studio side. To narrow down it, suggest you check if you are able to access files directly through web portal  url and if you are able to download file from web portal directly. This will also verify your permission. Make sure you have enough permission. Also check your url format, make sure you are using the right one. According to your screenshot, this sever name kind like a little mix up with Azure DevOps Service. Details please see my update reply.

Comment: Hi Satish Kumar S, any update on this issue? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi PatrickLu-MSFT, thanks for the update. previously its works fine me. One month back, my computer username is integrated/migrated with the Azure Active directory. Seems, after that onwards, getting the issue. Is this might be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, on [TFS side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928462/6309), you cannot really change the version of Git used.

Try cloning it through command line first, before opening it in VS 2019.

In that command line, try:

- raising `https.postbuffer` (`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360337/6309), or
- changing the [compression level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890786/6309) (`git config --global core.compression 1`).

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the reply. I have tried by running the above statements. Still getting the same. 

remote: Azure Repo
remote: Found 28047 objects to send. (32 ms)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: @SatishKumarS Do you get the error when cloning through VS 2019 or through a regular CMD?

Comment: sorry for the delay. I am getting the error while cloning through VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Please double check your url. Make sure you are using on-premise TFS/Azure DevOps url not cloud Azure DevOps Service.

Your url looks a little wired:

`http://xxx.azure.com:8080/tfs/DefaulCollection`

Did you sever name is  `xxx.azure.com`?

- For TFS and Azure DevOps url should be:

`git clone http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/project/_git/reponame`

- For Azure DevOps Service (previous name VSTS) should be:

`git clone  https://patricklu@dev.azure.com/patricklu/project/_git/reponame`

---

According to your description and screenshot, seems you were getting error when you click "Clone this repository" button in Visual Studio 2019.

Suggest your first check if you are able to **directly access git repo in web portal**.

To narrow down the issue, you could use [git command line to clone the repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line#clone-a-repo) instead of Visual Studio.

`git clone https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam`

- If you could not do this both from Visual Studio and Command line.
  Also not able to access the repo.

Then check your network setting,  in case behind a proxy, try to test without proxy first.

- If others all work properly, only fail with Visual Studio 2019.

You could [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), which may do the trick.