# git pull and clone error fatal: early EOF; fatal: unpack-objects failed

Tags: git, fatal-error

sorry to trouble you genius..

i am coming across a common problem that there is many solution on stack overflow, but those solution all does not suit for me. So at the end i have no choice but ask help from you genius again on the stack overflow.

1. i have a cloned repository on my server.
2. when i changed some code on my development machine and push to the remote git repository, everything worked smoothly.
3. the error start from when i pull data from the server. On the server, i command `git pull` the following error show up:

`remote: Counting objects: 66, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done. 
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly 
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed`

4. i tried this sloution: [fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed) 
   but i get error form step 2 `git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI>`

the error is :

`Cloning into 'sinolife'...
remote: Counting objects: 2783, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2199/2199), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.00 KiB/s

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed`

5. I also get a solution that there isn't enough swap memory. so i create a swap memory. At the beginning the swap is 0...After i config the swap, the `free -m` result is:

   ```
        total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   ```

Mem:          993        930         63          0         21         57

-/+ buffers/cache:        851        142

Swap:          499         16        483

but i also get the some error.

```
$git pull

remote: Counting objects: 66, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed

$git clone

Cloning into 'sinolife'...
remote: Counting objects: 2783, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2199/2199), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.00 KiB/s     
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

6. also [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning), follow the step ,but error come again. the following is my git config file

$git config -l

```
http.postbuffer=524288000
user.email= myemail@myemail.com
core.compression=0
core.compression=-1
core.compression=-1
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.compression=-1
core.packedgitlimit=512m
core.packedgitwindowsize=512m
remote.origin.url= my repository
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
pack.deltacachesize=2047m
pack.packsizelimit=2047m
pack.windowmemory=2047m
```

7. my environment:

   uname -a

   Linux VM-87-192-ubuntu 3.13.0-86-generic #131-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 23:33:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

   git --version

   git version 2.11.0

***8. hope some one can help me give my some hint.***

**9. question abstract**

i have a git repository, and already cloned in the server, but when `git pull`

```
remote: Counting objects: 66, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

when start a new clone  `git clone`

```
Cloning into 'sinolife'...
remote: Counting objects: 2057, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1740/1740), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.00 KiB/s     
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Your output shows that you are using bitbucket.org for your remote; have you contacted their support?  They seem to get this a lot so may have more experience dealing with this error, and surely they're better positioned than us to troubleshoot a connection with their servers

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger thank you for your advice..I can clone the repository on my development machine, there for, i conclude there is no connection issue to the server.. any way i will contact bitbucket for more help, thanks...

Comment: @wuxianghou Have you solve your problem? I got this problem too...

Comment: I use [gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) get the same issue so often(`fatal: unpack-objects failed`). Previous time pulling changes to complete new branch helped me. But this time I cannot get rid of it((

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve it again: jump to your previous commit. create there temporary branch. `git pull origin your_branch`. `git checkout your_branch` and pull again. I don't know why, but it solves the issue

Comment: @valijon can you please post an answer? If you solved this problem, your solution should not (just) be a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem by choosing EITHER of these to increase `postBuffer` size:

In terminal:

```
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

OR modify `gitconfig` file:

```
$ vim ~/.gitconfig # open gitconfig with ur favorite IDE
```

Add the following lines to at the end of `gitconfig` file:

```
[http]
        postBuffer = 1048576000
```

Comment: thank you. This solved the problem for me, though I had to use a bigger number than was mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the postbuffer of http to double? That works for me.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Times Network Connection Matters. you need to make sure whether you have proper internet connection or not. I too faced the same issue and resolved it via changing my Interne