# Git Hangs when Writing objects to push on bitbucket-ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

im trying to push my codes updates to bitbucket but i get stuck when git is writing objects. Nothing happens after a long time of hang with no further error or response from git. below is a sample of what im currently facing:

Writing objects:   4% (26/649), 138.22 MiB | 5.98 MiB/s

Kindly help on this. 
NOTE: im running on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You can try raising the `postbuffer` size using

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

This is properly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/6849424#6849424)

If that doesnt work,try uploading to a new branch and see if that works,then merge the branch.

It might also be possible that you are trying to upload huge binary files/folder using git. If that is the case,[this](https://git-lfs.github.com/) might help.