# gnu radio installation issue

Tags: git, gnu, ubuntu-16.04, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am facing  the  following error message  by using  command git clone

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull
>   function. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a GNU Radio issue per se. A Google search on "curl 56 GnuTLS recv error" turns up lots of references. Without knowing more about your machine, OS, versions, etc., the best that can be suggested is to do the same search and see if there are answers that may solve your problem.

I am pretty sure this is nothing to do with GNU Radio and everything to do with git and dependencies.