# Git Clone WebKit

Tags: git

When I use the command "git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git" to download a clone of the repository of the WwbKit, I aways  get this:

```
Cloning into 'WebKit'...
remote: Counting objects: 3609454, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (602466/602466), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly1.25 GiB | 356.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The following is my .gitconfig file content.

```
[gui]
    recentrepo = E:/git_test
[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
[user]
[alias]
        ci = commit -s
[pack]
        deltaCacheSize = 2047m
        packSizeLimit = 2047m
        windowMemory = 2047m
[core]
        packedGitLimit = 512m
        packedGitWindowSize = 512m
        compression = -1
[user]
        name = *********
        email = **********
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://webkit.org/getting-the-code/), the actual command seems to be this: `git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git WebKit`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning