# Strut's 1.0 maven project import not proper in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I have an strut's 1.0 application and its very old, i need to do some changes into it.

I pulled the master branch from the git as i am not able to pull the complete repository due to below error message:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyMiB | 20.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF 
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I referred below stackoverflow questions to resolve it but couldn't able to do so.

[fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

[The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/19286776)

But when i am importing the branch in eclipse using maven import its not importing properly.

Src folder is not coming in the eclipse and under Java Resources src folder java files are clubbed into the main.java folder.

Please find the below images for reference:

[Eclipse Project Import Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs48o.png)

[Eclipse Project Import Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAgRx.png)

I have tried to import the project as 'Existing Projects into the Workspace'
but that also didn't helped.

Can anyone provide any idea what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to classpath entry.

Need to change the below entry in the classpath:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
```

to

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
```

After changing the entry in .classpath and doing the project clean. It resolved the issue.