# Repo sync/Git clone is failed only from jenkins's slave

Tags: git, jenkins, repo

I execute `repo sync` from jenkins slave.

But error occured a specific repogitory.

```
Cloning into 'repo_name'...
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I execute it manualy(not from jenkins), repo sync was success.
Above error occured only when executed by jenkins's slave.

I also try to below cmd. But it is failed same error.

```
git clone ssh://user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port/path/to/reponame
```

I try to `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` with reference to the following.
But it is not fixed....

[The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

I add `--progress` and `--verbose` for investigation

```
git clone --progress --verbose ssh://user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port/path/to/reponame
```

git clone was succeed!!

Why It is failed from jenkins's slave.
Why It is succeed when added `--progress --verbose`.

Can I fixed it without `--progress`?
(repo sync seems without `--progress` when execute from jenkins.)

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to following

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9168

> When cloning a large repository over HTTP, the git server goes quiet for quite some time, busy computing a pack file. Normally, Apache is configured such that a prolonged inactivity in a socket will trigger a shutdown. So what the end user sees is that after a while, "git clone" fails by the unexpected connection reset by the server.

But, I can't configure server because server is public server.
So,

> If the user tries the same command from the shell, Git silently adds the --progress option (see the quote from the man page.) This keeps the socket chatty enough to avoid a shutdown from Apache.

On the other, repo can't add --progress option.
I don't have any other choice so I mod script of repo.
(.repo/repo/git_command.py)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, it can have different reasons.
Sometimes due to the low date speed of your slave machine.

Refer this ,

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed-779171803.html

Thanks

Comment: Why did I succeed when I added `--progress` as being caused low date speed.

Comment: --progress

Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless -q is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.