# Failing to push branch to git, getting "RPC failed ... errno 10054"

Tags: git, github

### The Problem

Trying to `push` changes made to a `git` branch, using the following line:
`git push origin my-branch`
But I keep on getting the following error:

```
>> git push origin my-branch

Counting objects: 616, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (611/611), done.
Writing objects: 100% (616/616), 207.46 MiB | 60.25 MiB/s, done.
Total 616 (delta 60), reused 63 (delta 5)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

### What I've Tried

1. I've tried making the buffer bigger [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/10524650), using these commands:

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`
`git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`
`git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000`
`git config --global http.postBuffer 4194304000`

Which all gave the exact same error.

2. I've tried setting the following configurations [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45117156/10524650) which also failed:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 500M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 100M
git config --global core.compression 0
```

### Additional Info

- I'm using github.
- My connection is ok.
- I'm trying to push a few dozens of 5-second audio files, which probably make the repository bigger than the typical one, but I don't think it's that of major anomaly.
- I've tried pushing from my `python` IDE (PyCharm) and from my desktop `GitHub` GUI thingy, but they also resulted in failures.

### Update

I untracked recordings using a `.gitignore` file, and tried to push again, but now it's stuck on this:

```
git push origin final-day
Counting objects: 631, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (623/623), done.
Writing objects: 100% (631/631), 207.47 MiB | 55.37 MiB/s, done.
Total 631 (delta 66), reused 63 (delta 5)
```

Why would this happen if the repo is now a normal, not-too-big repo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The error number 10054 is `WSAECONNRESET`, which means the connection was reset by the peer. That basically means that either the remote server or something in between intentionally closed the connection in an abrupt way.

That means that it's possible GitHub closed the connection, but it's likely instead that it's a proxy, network filter (e.g. anti-porn filter), or antivirus program. If you have one or more of those enabled, try disabling them (or, for antivirus, removing it altogether, since disabling it is often not effective) or connecting from a different location. This is definitely a network problem, and it's something that exists between Git and GitHub in the network stack that is causing it.

In general, raising `http.postBuffer` does not help problems and is not a good solution, and it will not help you here. There are many answers which suggest it, but unless you're using a broken HTTP/1.0 proxy that doesn't understand `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, it is unlikely to do anything useful.

Comment: I've disabled my antivirus, untracked the large files and I'm still getting this. Any idea of a way to fix this without the need to switch computers?

Comment: Your issue is related to the network. It could be the network you're connected to, or it could be something on your local computer. It's really impossible to know. (If it is the antivirus, usually disabling it doesn't solve the problem; you really have to remove it and restart.) Sorry for the bad news, but this is a common but generic problem.