# Git Clone Fails - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly. fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

My computer has proper configuration SSH, I got this error when trying to clone the repository:

I run this command to clone the repository

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/NewsFeed-library library1
```

It's giving me an error:

> Cloning into 'library1'...
>
> remote: Counting objects: 510, done.
>
> Connection to git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com closed by remote
>
> host. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

**How to resolve this error and why I got this error?**

---

**Edit:** I have already tried it but did not succeed:

```
#Windows
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

**and**

```
git config --global ssh.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Do [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/6849424) help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an alternative option to clone on http, run any of the below commands in gitbash and try to clone the repository, it should work.

1. `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
2. `git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

And, if you don't have the option of **http** and want to proceed with **ssh**.
You can configure SSH keepAlive either on the client or server.

**Configure on server**
*Edit*

```
~/.ssh/config  
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

**Configure on client**
*Edit* on */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

**e.g.**

```
echo 'ClientAliveInterval 60' | sudo tee --append /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

EDIT:
git config --global ssh.postBuffer 1048576000

Try increasing the buffer, i face the same probelm in my repository.

Answer (score 0):

You may do that once for all using the git config command:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 100000000
```