# Cloning repository from AWS Codecommit

Tags: laravel, git, amazon-web-services, version-control, clone

I am currently using SSH Key to clone repository from AWS Codecommit to my local machine. My

```
ssh git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

has successfully connected.

My problem is that when I run this:

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Project
```

it is cloning my project but after 100% of cloning, I keep getting this error

```
remote: Counting objects: 1024, done.
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer KiB/s
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I cannot find answers around google and hoping that someone will help me with this. What is the possible causes of these error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: And if you create another repo can you clone it?

Comment: Could you try to verbose, maybe you can get more info `git clone -vvv ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Project`

Comment: @loic.lopez yes, I tried cloning another repo but still the same output

Comment: @VadimSirbu It failed but displayed this before cloning 

`Server supports shallow`
`Server supports multi_ack_detailed`
`Server supports side-band-64k`
`Server supports allow-tip-sha1-in-want`
`Server supports allow-reachable-sha1-in-want`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try increasing the buffer

```
git config --global ssh.postBuffer 1048576000
```

---

If it doesn't work then use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) software,
It helped me when I faced the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59353753/git-clone-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-fatal-early-eof-f) like yours

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! its working now. Increasing postbuffer did a lot of help but in my case that is not the reason why its working. You guys should check your firewall, vpn connection or your network for their security purposes.

This site might help you resolving the issue 
[Git Clone Fails - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly. fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed-779171803.html)