# Connection to gitlab closed by remote host error message when pushing new created branch

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, push

Whenever I try to push my newly created branch I get this error message:

```
Connection to gitlab closed by remote.
```

[image: Error message]

I tried to push from SourceTree and GitDesktop, but I get the same error.

I don't think it's a connection issue since other repos work fine.
Could it be something with SSH Key? If yes, how can I fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

This is followed by a recent (Dec. 2020) [issue 12016](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/-/issues/12016)

It suggests for to raise the `postBuffer` size ([as I did in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/6309))

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

If could be a communication issue while uploading a large [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) object.

Comment: If it's a communication issue while uploading LFS object then how can it be fixed? I tried the command you suggested but still same issue

Comment: @محمدخيرالخلق For now, it would require for said cached LFS objects... to be smaller.

Comment: You mean pushing fewer files?

Comment: @محمدخيرالخلق Either fewer files, or make sure there is no one file too big in itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the reason!