# another git hung up unexpectedly curl openssl errno 104

Tags: android, git, curl

My failure happens on when I download android open source code(AOSP)， I get a lot of errors like:

```
platform/external/icu:
remote: Sending approximately 1.88 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 910, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (27/27)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

after checking with [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning)

I have already done

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Also, played with other configurations mentioned in the thread.

Bellow are my software versions

```
flynn@devops:/bigspace/db845$ repo --version
repo version v2.11.1
       (from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)
       (Thu, 7 Jan 2021 22:44:53 +0000)
repo launcher version 2.11
       (from /home/flynn/bin/repo)
       (currently at 2.11.1)
repo User-Agent git-repo/2.11.1 (Linux) git/2.25.1 Python/3.8.5
git 2.25.1
git User-Agent git/2.25.1 (Linux) git-repo/2.11.1
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0]
OS Linux 5.4.0-58-generic (#64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020)
CPU x86_64 (x86_64)
```

actually there are many more errors, just put some more here, I think they may caused by same issue:

```
remote: Counting objects: 171, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (422099/422099)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

device/google/redfin-kernel:
remote: Counting objects: 4558, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (4505/4505)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
platform/external/dokka:
remote: Sending approximately 873.24 MiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 157, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (15080/15080)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed


platform/external/icu:
remote: Sending approximately 1.88 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 909, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (125592/125592)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

platform/external/clang:
remote: Sending approximately 336.92 MiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 21099, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (580021/580021)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: `http.postBuffer` has no effect on clones and should not be used unless you've read the Git FAQ and understand what it does.  Are you using a proxy or a TLS MITM device, or anything else that intercepts connections?

Comment: hi @bk2204, thanks I got, I did played a lot with postBuffer, I think you are right, it takes no effect, and should not be the right solution to my case.

Regarding TLS MITM, I am not sure I understand it at all, is there any command check it out? I am using not proxy except global vpn from our company net work.