# How to resolve Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

My flutter application is not able to run on `2.5.0-5.3.pre` beta version. after then I searched for it then need to upgrade my flutter sdk so have upgraded to latest beta version  `2.6.0-5.2.pre` but still getting errors.
the errors with `place_picker-0.9.19-nullsafety` plugin. and not able to resolve it.

**ERRORS LOG:**

```
../../../../Workspace/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/place_picker-0.9.19-nullsafety/lib/widgets/rich_suggestion.dart:35:89: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../../Workspace/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
      TextSpan(text: boldText, style: style.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1!.color)),
                                                                                        ^^^^^
../../../../Workspace/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/place_picker-0.9.19-nullsafety/lib/widgets/search_input.dart:60:65: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../../Workspace/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
          Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1!.color),
                                                                ^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/brightroots/Workspace/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/brightroots/Workspace/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
```

**ERRORS:**

[image]

**MY CURRENT FUTTER VERSION:**

```
Flutter 2.6.0-5.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 400608f101 (8 days ago) • 2021-09-15 15:50:26 -0700
Engine • revision 1d521d89d8
Tools • Dart 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-82.2.beta)
```

Comment: use `bodyText1` instead

Comment: @Irsvmb you are saying , I have to edit plugins ?! Okay lemme try it.

Comment: @Irsvmb Thanks , It works. Actually I had never try to edit any plugins, always afraid of doing that.

Comment: The author should really be editing it. :)

Answer (score 5):

I was dealing with this error. In my case, it was because there was a dependency that was not compatible with flutter 2.5. I tried many solutions. But only this worked for me.

First add this to your pubspec.yaml

```
 charts_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/google/charts.git
      path: charts_flutter
```

as described on
[this link](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/676#issuecomment-915091444).

If you have an error saying: `remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning`,

then run this commands

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 500M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 100M
git config --global core.compression 0
```

[as described on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45117156/12756065).

This solved my problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30222535)

Answer (score 2):

Add them in dependencies and remove `body1` from `bodyText1`

```
charts_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/google/charts.git
      path: charts_flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use charts_flutter: ^0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown on the logs seems to be thrown by the plugin that you're using: `place_picker-0.9.19-nullsafety`. The logs indicate that the issue comes from `Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1`

Checking the Flutter docs, body1 on [TextTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html#instance-properties) is defined as `bodyText1`. You might want to consider updating how body1 is being called in TextTheme. Otherwise, you can track this [issue ticket](https://github.com/blackmann/locationpicker/issues/63) filed on GitHub related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the lines in the dart package like below and it will work. Of course the author should do this, but you can edit it yourself as well :)

**rich_suggestion.dart**

Original: TextSpan(text: boldText, style: style.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.**body1!**.color)),

New: TextSpan(text: boldText, style: style.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.**bodyText1!**.color)),

**search_input.dart**

Original: Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.**body1!**.color),

New: Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.**bodyText1!**.color),

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Guys usually we add dependencies before importing. but in this case first import that file(import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;) after that hover on package, it will give a option to add the dependencies then add the dependencies in this way. then your error will be solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).