# git push hangs (forever) and git-remote-https uses 99.5% CPU

Tags: git, macos, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm trying to `git push` a small project (712kb not taking into account the `.git` folder) to a new repo, hosted on Google Source Repositories, and the push never finishes. It stops right after printing the `Total` message (hangs for at least hours).

```
Enumerating objects: 77, done.
Counting objects: 100% (77/77), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
Writing objects: 100% (77/77), 131.62 KiB | 6.93 MiB/s, done.
Total 77 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

The only **workaround was to split the commit into two smaller commits** (no specific files need to be separated into the second commit; any random files do the trick). This confirms that it's not an auth issue. But it's **not a real solution**.

None of the answers I've found fix the issue. I'm mainly referring to :

- increase `http.postBuffer` size (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/1403417)
- update the git version (to use git latest version instead of Apple XCode's one)

I'm looking for **other ideas** to identify a proper solution to this issue.

Comment: The fact that it printed the total+delta+reused numbers means that as far as *Git* was concerned, it was done. Why the https remote started to spin is a different question and will require debugging the https remote code and/or the receiver on the Google side (this may get tricky!).

Comment: Changing the size of the `http.postBuffer` to a smaller size fixed the issue. Maybe this buffer size is used by `git-remote-https` which is why it solved the issue

Comment: If you have a reliable reproducer (a repository or setup instructions you can share), send it to the Git mailing list (git@vger.kernel.org) and someone will look into it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you could try to lower the size of `http.postBuffer` instead of increasing it. I remember it did the trick for me when I faced the same problem

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, this actually worked! A `git config http.postBuffer 16384` fixed the push issue. The push has completed in a few seconds.

**I double checked** and set the postBuffer to a larger value again (1Mb) and it failed again.

If someone knows why, I'd be interested in understanding more. Could this be related to Google Source Repositories (vs Github where people seem to have solved the problem by *increasing* the size of this buffer)?

Comment: This worked for me again, trying to push to another git server (GitLab CE instance). So this has nothing to do with Google Source Repositories. When I had the initial problem, it was on another Mac (an M1 Mac) and this time it's on a 2015 MBP. So maybe it's related to my (ADSL) connection?

Comment: For the record, this happened to me again today and the solution fixed the issue again (same M1 Mac). But this time I'm no longer on an ADSL connection but a Fiber one. Still a mystery why this happens from time to time!