# Why does not git fully download dependent libraries throw submodule

Tags: git

My code has some dependent libraries throw `submodule`, I clone the codes throw two ways:

```
git clone --recursive ***
```

or

```
git submodule update --init --remote --recursive
```

but neither of them works, after I clone the code, the size of dependent libraries are about 130 like this

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 130 Aug 25 11:51 libaddress_sorting.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 131 Aug 25 11:51 libares.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 133 Aug 25 11:51 libboringssl.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 132 Aug 25 11:51 libgpr.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 134 Aug 25 11:51 libgrpc.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 133 Aug 25 11:51 libgrpc++.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 133 Aug 25 11:51 libgrpc_abseil.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 133 Aug 25 11:51 libgrpc++_alts.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 131 Aug 25 11:51 libgrpc_csharp_ext.a
```

but their real sizes are

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen     46850 Aug 10 15:32 libaddress_sorting.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen    824784 Aug 10 15:32 libares.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen  27209910 Aug 10 15:32 libboringssl.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen   1213616 Aug 10 15:32 libgpr.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen 172648038 Aug 10 15:32 libgrpc.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen  52885946 Aug 10 15:32 libgrpc++.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen  10001966 Aug 10 15:32 libgrpc_abseil.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen  28759698 Aug 10 15:32 libgrpc++_alts.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 klen klen    127288 Aug 10 15:32 libgrpc_csharp_ext.a
```

`git` version is 1.8.3.1, My question is why can not `git` clone the libraries fully?

Comment: "Clone" is probably not the problem.  It sounds like somebody messed up at "commit".  SUGGESTION: 1) Copy your project, including the .a files, to a temp directory. 2) Create a NEW Git repo locally, in the temp directory. 3) Commit everything (git add ., then  git commit -m "some msg")  4) Verify whether or not the .a files were saved correctly - and can be restored correctly - locally.  5) Post back what you find.

Comment: It looks like those are git LFS pointers. Install git lfs on your computer and try again.

Comment: @paulsm4 Probably not because of this, as I can download these libraries on other computers correctlly.

Comment: @fredrik  yes, it works for me, I install `git-lfs` and it works now

Comment: Frankly, I never heard of "git-lfs" before.  Good to know: +1.  NOTE: git-lfs is an "extension"; it's definitely NOT an intrinsic feature of Git itself.   I guess your remote repo was configured to use it ... but nobody ever gave you the memo.  Interesting article: https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2021/05/12/why-you-shouldn%27t-use-git-lfs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fredrik said, After install `git-lfs`, I can download the libraries fully.

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash

sudo yum update

sudo yum install git-lfs
```

I am not sure if this installation method works for everyone, see [this](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is linked to the [`http.postBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/6309) when those librairies were added and pushed.

But ideally, you would not add them to a Git repository in the first place.
Those kind of deliverables belongs to an artifact referential, like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).
That way, you can add to your project a config file *declaring* your dependencies (like a [`pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies)), instead of asking a *source* control system like Git to restore huge files.

The other approach would be to use [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), but it might not be fully supported by an old Git 1.8.x from a RHEL 7.x or 8.X.