# How to solve'fatal: index-pack failed'?

Tags: git

I run:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_slam$ git clone       git://github.com/ethz-asl/ros-mapping.git ethzasl_mapping
  Initialized empty Git repository in       /home/ira/code/ros/sam_slam/ethzasl_mapping/.git/      
  remote: Counting objects: 784, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (238/238), done.
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyiB | 18 KiB/s   
  fatal: early EOFs:  31% (244/784), 52.00 KiB | 18 KiB/s   
  fatal: index-pack failed
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_slam$
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_slam$ git clone       git://github.com/ethz-asl/ros-mapping.git ethzasl_mapping
  Initialized empty Git repository in       /home/ira/code/ros/sam_slam/ethzasl_mapping/.git/
  remote: Counting objects: 784, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (238/238), done.
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyiB | 18 KiB/s   
  fatal: early EOFs:  31% (244/784), 52.00 KiB | 18 KiB/s   
  fatal: index-pack failed
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_slam$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Comment: The clone just worked for me, is this something temporary that's cleared up now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using an unusual protocol combination (like in "[Git checking out problem `[fatal: early EOFs]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505644/git-checking-out-problem-fatal-early-eofs)"), this is a sign of a GitHub server hiccup.

See its [GitHub system status page](https://status.github.com/):

```
May 25, 2012 – minor interruption occurred

06:44 am PST
All systems are back to normal.

06:30 am PST
Investigating intermittent 'remote end hung up unexpectedly' errors
```

It seems to have some residual side-effects which can still be seen after the official "resolution time" mentioned by GitHub.