# GIT able to push the zipped file but get fatal: early EOF when pushing the unzipped contents -

Tags: git, mount, msysgit

For any directory A(having several subfolders) in the git directory,  if I zip directory A to A.zip, I am able to push the zipped file, A.zip to the Remote GIT repository.
However, when I try to push the unzipped directory(A) directly, the push fails with the following exception:

```
Counting objects: 110, done.
Writing objects: 100% (109/109), 12.60 MiB | 445 KiB/s, done.
Total 109 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: early EOF
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To user@dev-server:/mnt/repositories/repo-1/test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'user@dev-server:/mnt/git-repositories/repo1/test.git'
```

Client is on Windows 7 & Remote GIT server is RHEL 6
Msysgit 1.7.6 on server and 1.8.2 on client
Get same issue from other workstation machines uses as clients.
This problem usually happens for directory sizes > 8-10 MB

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This issue occurs only when the remote repository is on a mounted file-system instead of a normal file-system

Also if I try to push my sub-directories one-by-one, individually(each under 1Mb) it works

Comment: Does this happen if you push to the server over ssh instead of to the network mounted repository?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009493/git-push-fails-with-fatal-early-eof-when-pushing-but-only-on-one-file

Comment: @Andrew This issue happens only for mounted file-systems. For usual file system, it works fine

Comment: @user2394848: Could you elaborate on "mounted file-system"? (do you mean a bind mount? File systems are usually mounted to be used.)

Comment: @Hasturkun yes a bind mount... physically located on some other remote machine

Comment: @Keval tried the suggestions in yr mentioned post.. still getting the same issue

Comment: @user2394848: Okay, that's not a bind mount (which allow you to remount part of the file hierarchy elsewhere). What sort of remote filesystem are you mounting? CIFS/SMB? NFS? What sort of system is hosting the fs?

Answer (score 0):

try:
git config pack.windowMemory 10m git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m then retry the git clone

or git gc