# Pushing to GitHub - failed pushing to... (Repo) Premature EOF

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, github, egit

Trying to push a project created before, to a private repository, it is the first commit to master branch remote, the repository is empty, just with a README file.

The push takes a long time and throws this error:

Failed pushing to... (Repo) Premature EOF

What is the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push fails with "fatal: early EOF" when PUSHing but only on one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009493/git-push-fails-with-fatal-early-eof-when-pushing-but-only-on-one-file)

Answer (score 0):

Edit local `.git/config` to add `compression = 0` in [core] section.