# Git push heroku master fails with "remote: fatal: early EOF error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, cloud9-ide

Beginner here stumped as to why my git pushes to Heroku are failing all of a sudden:

```
a101291@pinteresting:~/workspace (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 2043, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1997/1997), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2021/2021), 35.58 MiB | 4.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 2021 (delta 847), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

...now it hangs for ~15 minutes and then:

```
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To https://git.heroku.com/omr101291.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
```

Tried again a few times to no avail. Also tried restarting the dyno and heroku repo:rebuild but still no luck. I am running this from an Ubuntu instance on Cloud9 IDE and the repo is here: https://github.com/101291/pinteresting
(pushes to Github are working fine).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I would try running `git repack` on your local repository before trying to push again. Make a backup beforehand if you do not have one, just to be sure.

Comment: Also see a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505644/git-checking-out-problem-fatal-early-eofs

Comment: Just tried `git repack` still no luck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue (I was trying to push what turned out to be really large files!) and what fixed it was: 
`git push heroku master --no-thin`

If you're interested, here is a brief explanation from the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/1.8.3.2):

> --[no-]thin These options are passed to git-send-pack[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/1.8.3.2). A thin transfer significantly reduces the amount of sent data when the sender
>   and receiver share many of the same objects in common. The default is
>   --thin.