# Visual Studio Failed to clone the remote repository (Early EOF) - GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently followed this guide [Installing a Git Server using Apache (WebDAV) on Ubuntu Server 12.04](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2012/07/23/installing-a-git-server-using-apache-webdav-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/) to setup a local Git Server using Apache (WebDAV).

I have pushed my source code to the Git Server through command prompt.

I want to be able to do is pull / push / commit this source code using Visual Studio. From what I have read its appears to be possible. I'm getting the following error message when you try and clone this source code through visual studio:

```
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Early EOF
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an https or ssh url?

Comment: Hi @VonC I am using http

Comment: Would a git pull work in command line? If not, would any of the suggestions of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22317479/6309 work?

Comment: VS does not speak the old WebDAV protocol ("dumb http").  It only speaks the "smart http" protocol.  Check out http://brakkee.org/site/2011/08/06/git-server-setup-on-linux-using-smart-http/ for example.

Answer (score 3):

For this 2015 question to be resolved in 2017 (for [Morgan G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3837268/morgan-g)), you should use a recent Git HTTP server, with a recent Visual Studio and a recent Git.

That is because:

- https url don't use anymore the [old webdav protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), but the more [modern "smart http"](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) and its `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend` script. Normally, we no longer use `DAV on` in an Apache configuration for Git purposes.
- A [more recent version of Visual Studio, called "15" switched from libgit2 to Git itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40059664/6309).
- For big Git repo being cloned, [you would need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18497483/6309) (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/6309)):

  ```
  git config --global --add core.compression -1
  git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
  ```