# Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly while pushing back to git repository

Tags: github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [github: newbie problems -> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617113/github-newbie-problems-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end)

please see the below command ,

```
$ git clone git://github.com/{user_name}/{project_name}.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dengx/rorBlog_demo/rorblog/.git/
```

Changing the files and committing it, so i need to push back to git repository.

```
$ git push git@github.com/{user_name}/{project_name}.git master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

so, i copy the ssh-key of the repository to my file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, and then push again,

```
$ git push git@github.com/{user_name}/{project_name}.git master
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Now, what should i do ,  thanks any helps.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Googled "Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly", first result an exact SO dupe:

[GitHub: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617113/github-newbie-problems-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end-h) which links here in the accepted answer (from the original poster, no less): http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

Comment: I new a ssh-key in other local repository, and add the new ssh-key to github repository, then try again `ssh -T git@github.com`. it show me this error `Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
`

Comment: I solved this problem myself, it needs to add the ssh-key to admin panel of that project , not in account setting. Here is the right link for adding your deploy key, `https://github.com/{user_name}/{project_name}/admin`

Comment: @coolesting  are these same key used for Account Settings? or generate new

Comment: You can deploy your public keys to github using url: https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>/settings/keys

Comment: @johnny : is there any way to remove public key/ ssh and back normal to https port