# Why can't I deploy rails project running on legacy stack (bamboo)?

Tags: heroku

I have not yet migrated my rails project to the cedar stack.
I want to push some bug fixes to my production app on heroku,
but here is the response:

```
$ git push heroku master
remote: !   bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack not supported.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

Is it still possible to deploy legacy apps running on bamboo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is resolved by using git over ssh, instead of over https.
https transport is unsupported on the legacy bamboo stack.  Here's
the heroku article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#ssh-git-transport

For ssh transport, you have to jump through a few hoops to bring up
your connection.  I found [this article very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206779/git-push-heroku-master-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end-hung).

Comment: This answer sent me in the right direction, thanks! However, SSH transport has been disabled, so I had to download my app using slugs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73671284/549189)