# Can't clone heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I can't clone my heroku app (more than 2 years older) using the clone command because I get this error:

bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack not supported

What I have to do?

Comment: You can try upgrading the stack, as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use ssh instead of https for the old stacks.

```
> heroku git:clone --ssh-git -a app
```

where app is the name of your heroku app

Comment: For those who are cleaning up old repos like me; you might need to add your ssh keys again with `heroku keys:add` before downloading with ssh. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding-keys-to-heroku

Answer (score 4):

SSH transport has been disabled in March 2022:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2215
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2365

I had to download the code for an old project using slugs:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs
heroku slugs:download -a yourapp
```

Which produced an error:

```
Downloading... ████████████████████████▏  100% 00:00 564kB                                                                                                                                                                                   
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
 ▸    Command failed: tar -xf yourapp/slug.tar.gz -C yourapp
 ▸    tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
 ▸
```

So I installed squashfs as suggested [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-slugs/issues/21):

```
brew install squashfs
cd yourapp
unsquashfs -f -d out slug.tar.gz
```

Which will leave you with the code in the `out` directory.