# How to use git with Aptana

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I have Git Extensions set up on my Windows 7 box and I also have Aptana 3. I have Git Extensions working with my depository.  I set up a Apatana project and pointed at the git directory for my project. I get the pull/push options in the Gear icon.

When I try to pull I get  the error:
**Permission denied (publickey).

  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

I have spent a while on Goodle trying to find out the answer without any luck.

I guess I need to d sort sort of public key thing but don't know what.

Ben

Comment: Hi @user1826834 - I think this question and answer addresses the same thing you're looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3618055/2441384