# Permission denied (publickey) on push into remote git-server

Tags: git

I try create new repositories on my remote git-server

```
cd /var/www/vhost/example.com
sudo git init
sudo git remote add origin ssh://git@111.111.111.111:30000/home/git/repositories/example.git
sudo git add .
sudo git commit -a -m "Create empty example.com dir"
sudo git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

My ssh config:

```
Host 111.111.111.111
User git
Port 30000
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

My gitosis-admin.conf

```
[gitosis]

[group gitosis-admin]
members = git@111.111.111.111
writable = gitosis-admin

[group example-com]
members = git@111.111.111.111 user@user
writable = example-com
```

Get error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can do

```
ssh git@111.111.111.111
```

no problem, but can't do push. What i doing wrong? I had also looked into similar previous question [GitHub: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617113/github-newbie-problems-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end)  , but i don't use github.

**UPDATE:** Ok, i think problem in sudo.

This command complete whitout some sort of error:

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

This command:

```
sudo git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

complete with error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: The remote URL should be `ssh://git@111.111.111.111:30000/example.git` if it works remotely like gitolite nowaday does. Btw. you should really switch to [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/), it’s gitosis’ successor.

Comment: no matter, i take error Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Comment: When you ssh into it normally, do you get a shell? If yes, you need to use a different public key for your repository and the standard ssh access.

Comment: can be problem case i use "sudo git push" instead of "git push"?

Comment: Not really, it should work just with `git push`, so it should definitely work with even more rights.

Answer (score 0):

wehre die you Store your SSH config, normally the config is in the Home Directory, so root has a different Home Directory and also a different SSH config, you have to save the config in the Home Directory of root i think.

Answer (score 0):

Re-run any git command by following with `GIT_TRACE=1`, e.g.

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

So you can see more output and executed commands to check why git is failing.

If working on Windows, define `GIT_TRACE` user variable with any value, so it'll enable debug mode for all git commands. Remove when not needed.

You may also use: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv"` (Git 2.3.0+).