# Committing a Project to Github

Tags: git, github, cygwin

I have a new app I am trying to commit to my git account. I cannot seem to commit it:

```
$ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).

$ ssh-add -1
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

When checking my SSH, I get this error:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to github.com [204.232.175.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-      6+squeeze1+github12
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Fletch/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Fletch/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have a GIT account, I have their native client AND I have an additional SSH key with the id_rsa.pub file created, I have my global user setting created, I have a repository created in GitHub, I have all relevant SSH agents within Cygwin installed, I have all firewall products disabled when installing Cygwin and working with the terminal.

The only thing I can troubleshoot is:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/home/Fletch/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

However, I created this file and see the SSH key in my account. I have searched all through  similar posts and cannot seem to find a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [github: newbie problems -> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617113/github-newbie-problems-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end)

Answer (score 0):

I use cygwin with both github and bitbucket and had similar issues until I read [Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git)

It shows how to setup the ssh keys and how to automatically run a ssh-agent when you start bash (or Git Bash) the first time.

Comment: I went through your suggested page. I went through all the instructions and still could not resolve my problem. I have been through at least 4 similar troubleshooting guides and still have not been successful at resolving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in another post: [GitHub: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617113/github-newbie-problems-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end)

**I had this problem, but none of the solutions above worked. I could clone and fetch but couldn't push. Eventually, I figured out the problem was in the url in my .git/config, it should be:
git@github.com:/
(not ssh://github.com//.git or https://github.com//.git).**