# tortoisegit = fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly but not with git bash

Tags: git, bash, tortoisegit

The problems a bit of a weird one and after about 1 week of searching and just using bash i thought i'd ask you dudes.

Simple really whenever i try to push or pull via tortoisegit it asks me for the log in details once i enter them i get 'fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly'. I thought maybe i wasn't the right user so i changed myself to be the root: url = ssh://root@... but still not luck.

No idea what it might but maybe somebody else has had the same problem.

Any Clues guys?

**[Edit]**
Fixed this sadly by uninstalling `tortoisegit` on windows, restarting and then reinstalling.

Comment: Are you using SSH pubkey authentication? If so, is tortoisegit using the same SSH as git bash? If not, does tortoisegit's ssh have the right key registered?

Comment: yikes, i'm going to have to check this out. Not sure how to check which ssh git bash is using though :s?

Comment: So i got this working in the end, i reinstalled everything and somehow it works :\ sorry to not help at all.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this sadly by uninstalling tortoisegit on windows, restarting and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue, and reinstalling did not help.  I don't know if there was a server change *(I'm not using Github)*, or if it's because I upgraded to Tortoise Git 1.8, or what.  But, it used to ask for my username every time I tried to connect, while now it simply gives that error.

Turns out it was a settings issue.  In the repository, under `Tortoise Git --> settings --> remote`, the URL was set to `hostname.com:myRepo`.  This used to work, but apparently not anymore; I changed it to `username@hostname.com:myRepo`.

Now it works, and as a bonus it no longer asks me to enter my username every time I try to push/pull.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. After i changed https to http in the URL everything worked fine. Your connection wont be secure though.

When pulling files i use this URL

http://github.com/*user* / *folder*

Comment: heh dude, i wasn't using github :) i have git installed on my server. As simple as that was to do :)